# So I've created a new branch, now how do I work with a cloned set of separate files?

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I'm still relatively inexperienced using github, especially so with the command prompt, with 99% of my experience coming directly via the github windows application.

I am trying to configure my repository as follows:

Up until now, I have been working directly off the master branch. But now I need to upgrade a large section of code, and obviously don't want to deploy it until it's done. However, I still need to be able to deploy quick updates for unrelated requests using the original code.

I've managed to create a new branch, but I am unable to figure out how to separate the code files, so that I can work on them separately.

Any help/info on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean under "separate the code files"? Because you generally have very similar file sets under all the branches (except the differences between the branches of course).

Comment: What I mean is that on my local machine, I have one directory that contains all the files for my project. When I created my branch, there is still only one set of files on my local machine. This is problematic, because while I spend the next couple weeks working on the large update, I will likely need to deploy small unrelated updates that shouldn't have to wait until I am done with the large project. If there is only one set of files, I won't be able to deploy any updates to the live server without deploying the unfinished larger project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I created my branch, there is still only one set of files on my local machine.

Yes, that is expected.

> This is problematic, because while I spend the next couple weeks working on the large update, I will likely need to deploy small unrelated updates that shouldn't have to wait until I am done with the large project.

Git handles your branches for you, usually in a single directory.

While `master` is checked out you can keep working directly on it like you used to. New commits will go onto the `master` branch.

After doing this, if you check your new branch out (let's call it `newbranch`) your files will be reset to how they look in `newbranch`. Then you can work on `newbranch` and make commits that go on that branch.

Every time you `git checkout <somebranch>` Git will update your working copy accordingly, and new commits will go onto the active branch.

There is one detail here that often confuses new users: *uncommitted changes don't belong to any branch*. That is, if you are on `master` and you modify some files, but don't commit them, and then `git checkout newbranch` your changes will follow you. This is by design, and there is lots of material online discussing this feature.

Finally, if your version of Git is new enough (version 2.5 or later) you can use the `git worktree` command to create multiple working directories, each linked to a particular branch. Note that this is an experimental feature, and it shouldn't yet be used with submodules.

You can read more about this feature [on GitHub's blog](https://github.com/blog/2042-git-2-5-including-multiple-worktrees-and-triangular-workflows) or elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is literally the most amazing feature I've learned to date